# How to get access token from AuthenticationFlowContext on keycloak custom authenticator

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-services

I need to call one external API from the Keycloak custom authenticator authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) method, for that, I need keycloak access token.
How to get the access token from the AuthenticationFlowContext.

Authenticator class:

```
public class CMAuthenticator implements Authenticator
{
   @Override
   public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context)
   {
     try
     {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();

        final String userName = formData.getFirst("username");
        final String pwd = formData.getFirst("password");

        String cmLoginURL = getCMAuthenticatorConfig(context);

        String loginObj = "{\"username\": \"" + userName + "\", \"password\":\"" + pwd + "\"}";
        Entity<String> entity = Entity.text(loginObj);

        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(cmLoginURL);

        Response response = target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).post(entity);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200)
        {
            context.getEvent().user(context.getUser());
            context.getEvent().error(Errors.ACCESS_DENIED);
            context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER);

            return;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        context.getEvent().user(context.getUser());
        context.getEvent().error(Errors.ACCESS_DENIED);
        context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER);

        return;
     }

     context.success();
  }
}
```

Comment: During authentication process/flow there is no token available in the AuthenticationFlowContext. The whole purpose of authentication flow is to decide whether to issue a token or not. Why do you need a token to call your external API at this point?

Comment: Thanks for your response @sventorben, I've to call our custom login API with username and password entered, but that external application is expecting an authorization token in the header.